# Attempting to connect a raspberry pi to an allied vision camera

Tags: ethernet, dhcp

[image]Here is my situation: I have an Allied Vision Mako 419-C camera attached via a Power-over Ethernet (PoE) connection to a Raspberry Pi-4. Using the bash console on the Raspberry Pi, I have installed Vimba Python from github, and the vimba SDK (64 bit ARM) from the Allied Vision website (and installed the GigE install.sh file). The allied vision camera is displaying a green light indicating that its powered, and an orange light which I think means its sending data. However, when I try to run the example python script that Allied Vision provides to detect a camera, nothing is detected. Additionally, when I run the Vimba Viewer software, it doesn't detect the camera despite it being connected via ethernet. I believe the issue lies with the ethernet connection between the Raspberry Pi and the camera, but honestly, I'm not sure. Can anyone suggest any potential fixes? For clarity, someone has suggested using the Raspberry Pi as a DHCP server. Is there any merit to this idea?

(EDIT: I've attached a labelled diagram of my setup)

Comment: please edit your question ... add a diagram of how the camera is interfaced with the Raspberry Pi ... include all components in the diagram

Answer (score 0):

From your description and diagram of your setup, I understand: 1) you verified your Raspberry Pi and Mako G-419-C camera can source power from your PoE network switch (hopefully, IEEE 802.3af and/or 802.3at Type 1 compliant). 2) the Vimba Viewer software running on the Raspberry Pi host cannot detect the Mako G-419-C camera.

Yes, there may be merit to the DHCP server suggestion. If not previously configured by the Vimba Viewer, the Mako G-419-C has DHCP enabled by default. Thus, if you have a DHCP server on the same network you may be able to view the IP address assigned to the Mako G-419-C and ping it from the Raspberry Pi to confirm the network path.